# Grails interprets and closes HTML meta tag

Tags: grails, gsp

In my Grails GSP file I'm using the HTML meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

The problem is that Grails closes this tag and renders it as:

```
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
```

This fails W3C's HTML validation (since my doctype is HTML and not XHTML).
Is there a fix for this? How can I get Grails to not interpret the
meta tag?

I'm using grails-1.2-M4.

**Follow up:**
I create the Grails bug [GRAILS-5696](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-5696) for this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure that this is the most beautiful solution, but at least it will work for your case:

```
<%= '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">' %>
```

Well...this does not work since it is preprocessed by Grails before displayed as is.

So the only solution I see is to create a TagLib and output the content like this:

```
class MetaTagLib {

    static namespace = 'my'

    def meta = {
        out << "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\"/>"
    }
}
```

and use it like:

```
<my:meta />
```

It works. Tested.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work and results in <sitemesh:captureMeta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

Comment: Yes it works. I'm going to file this as a Grails bug. I should be able to produce 100% valid HTML using Grails.

Answer (score 0):

You could validate as HTML5 instead of HTML 4.01, by using `<!DOCTYPE html>` ([that's it, really](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/syntax.html#the-doctype)!). HTML5 [allows trailing slashes even in the HTML syntax](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/syntax.html#start-tags), in order to allow for systems like this that produce pseudo-XHTML.

Of course, HTML5 is not yet a finished standard; it may change. I think that this aspect of it is unlikely to be changed, but there is still some fairly contentious debate about a lot of the new HTML5 features, so keep in mind that it's not yet finalized.